# How to load a set of objects when Hibernate Lazy Fetchtype is used?

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I have a Hibernate domain class (let's say PetOwner) with a one to many relationship with another class(Pets)

[PetOwner (1)---------(*) Pet]

Due to a drastic change required to improve the performance I had to change the fetchtype of the 
getPets() method in PetOwner class to be lazy.

So the current mapping looks as follows

```
@OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "petowner")
public Set<Pet> getPets() {
    if (pets == null) {
       pets = new HashSet<Pet>();
    }
    return pets;
}
```

For some test classes, the getPets() method is used after a PetOwner is found using the retrievePetOwnerById() method. After the changes to mapping this causes **LazyInitializationException**.(As the object-graph is not fully loaded due to the change of fetch type)

I used a not elegant workaround by adding a method like the one shown below to the DefaultPetOwnerService.

```
public PetOwner retrievePetOwnerByIdWithPets(Long petOwnerId) {
        PetOwner petOwner = retrievePetOwnerById(petOwnerId);
        int size = petOwner.getPets().size();
        return petOwner;
    }
```

**petOwner.getPets().size()** has to be used because the pets won't be loaded till some operation on the list is done. 
When I use the new method, the LazyInitializationException can be overcome. But it's a hack and I'm searching a way to 
do this more neatly. Are there any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Hibernate#initialize(Object)](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/Hibernate.html#initialize(java.lang.Object)) to initialize your object.  It should resolve the collection reference.

I'm curious why you want "eager" fetching without setting the fetch type to be eager though.